# Not able to run the Windows Workflow Foundation sample HiringRequest

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

I am currently exploring the possibilities of WF. Now i downloaded some sample from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en). I wanted to take a look at the hiring request sample applications which is also showed in one of the webcasts from [enpoint.tv.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-The-FlowChart-Activity)

When I start op the project and want to see how the HiringRequestProcess.xaml looks like I get errors.

It's says that the x:string, x:TypeArguments etc cannot be resolved.

Anyone has any idea's how I can get the sample running? I'm running vs2010 ultimate as an administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now. I extracted all files to the root of my drive and now it seems to work.